# SFINAE with multi-layer type determination

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, sfinae

The following code specializes two versions of f(). The first detects a vector and returns an iterator. The second takes all other types and returns a copy.

This fails to compile on VC 2010 with an error in GetIter2 that GetIter::type doesn't exist. This is only when resolving a call to f() with a non-vector. If I remove one layer of type indirection, using GetIter instead of GetIter2 (see commented line) for the return type, then things work fine.

I guess I want to know if this a compiler bug or correct behavior. If this looks weird it's because it's a reduction of a problem I'm having using boost::range_iterator where I can't just remove what GetIter2 represents.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct GetIter {
};

template<typename T>
struct GetIter<vector<T>> {
    typedef typename vector<T>::iterator type;
};

template<typename T>
struct GetIter2
{
    typedef typename GetIter<T>::type type;
};

template<typename T>
typename enable_if<is_same<T, vector<int>>::value, typename GetIter2<T>::type>::type
//typename enable_if<is_same<T, vector<int>>::value, typename GetIter<T>::type>::type
f(T & t) {
    return t.begin();
}

template<typename T>
typename enable_if<!is_same<T, vector<int>>::value, T>::type
f(T & t) {
    return t;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<int> v(2);
    int i = 6;

    f(v);
    f(i);  // error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'GetIter<T>'

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Here is the actual problem I'm trying to solve. The second call to copy() with an iterator as the second argument causes a similar error as above on the boost::mpl::eval_if_c object.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/tti/has_type.hpp>

BOOST_TTI_TRAIT_HAS_TYPE(has_iterator, iterator)

template<typename InCont, typename Out>
typename enable_if<has_iterator<Out>::value, typename boost::range_iterator<Out>::type>::type
copy(InCont const & in_cont, Out & out_cont)
{
    return std::copy(boost::begin(in_cont), boost::end(in_cont), boost::begin(out_cont));
}

template<typename InCont, typename Out>
typename enable_if<!has_iterator<Out>::value, Out>::type
copy(InCont const & in_cont, Out & out_iter)
{
    return std::copy(boost::begin(in_cont), boost::end(in_cont), out_iter);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;

    copy(v1, v2);
    copy(v1, v2.begin());  // error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'boost::mpl::eval_if_c<C,F1,F2>'

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2:
The original problem was fixed in a recent version of boost::range_iterator. Once I patched that things got easier. Here's what I've landed on, checking for containers with boost::has_range_iterator:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/range.hpp>

template<typename InCont, typename Out>
typename boost::range_iterator<Out>::type
copy(InCont const & in_cont, Out & out_cont)
{
    return std::copy(boost::begin(in_cont), boost::end(in_cont), boost::begin(out_cont));
}

template<typename InCont, typename Out>
typename enable_if<!boost::has_range_iterator<Out>::value, Out>::type
copy(InCont const & in_cont, Out out_iter)
{
    return std::copy(boost::begin(in_cont), boost::end(in_cont), out_iter);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;

    copy(v1, v2);
    copy(v1, v2.begin());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your new example doesn't compile because your overload taking an iterator takes it by reference - if you just remove the `&` in `Out & out_iter`, it compiles fine.

Comment: I turns out the SFINAE problem in boost::range_iterator I was hitting was fixed in a recent release (I was on 1.58). Once I updated that the broken example compiled verbatim for me (MSVC). I think removing the ref makes sense though. I posted my results above. Thanks so much for your help. I wish I could accept 2 answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still trying to find the relevant part of the standard to explain why this doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the substitution of `GetIter2<T>` not failing but subsequently accessing `GetIter2<T>::type` where it then determines that `GetIter<T>::type` doesn't exist. By making the `GetIter2<T>` template fail to substitute right away you don't get the error. You can do that by changing its definition slightly:

```
template<typename T, typename ST = typename GetIter<T>::type>
struct GetIter2
{
    typedef ST type;
};
```

I was able to get your real example working without modifying boost types with the following code:

```
template<typename InCont, typename Out, typename = typename enable_if<has_iterator<Out>::value>::type>
typename boost::range_iterator<Out>::type
copy(InCont const & in_cont, Out & out_cont)
{
    return std::copy(boost::begin(in_cont), boost::end(in_cont), boost::begin(out_cont));
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. See above edits for the real situation I'm solving. Based on your suggestion I added template argument "typename ST = typename range_const_iterator<typename remove_const<typename remove_reference<C>::type>::type>::type" to boost::range_iterator I got it to work. 

I had to remove another seemingly unused template argument "typename Enabler=void" to not get a "too many template arguments" error. Hopefully it is not important but I can't tell. It makes no sense to me what it would be for.

Comment: The real example also begs the question of is this even a  good approach. I guess things without an iterator sub-type can still be containers, especially when using boost::range, so the enable_if might be better off testing if a range_iterator can be made from the Out object...perhaps.

Comment: It turns out the SFINAE problem with range_iterator has been patched since boost 1.58. 1.60 works as expected. There is also a has_range_iterator trait that does exactly what I want for container detection. Thanks for your help. This was a huge time suck for just needing to update boost but I learned a lot about SFIANE.

Answer (score 1):

**Why it doesn't work**

The rule is, from [temp.deduct], emphasis mine:

> Only invalid types and expressions in the **immediate context** of the function type and its template parameter types can result in a deduction failure.

The immediate context is what you see in the declaration itself. The failure that happens when you try to substitute `T=int` isn't in the immediate context of `typename GetIter2<T>::type` - the failure happens when trying to determine what that type actually is and seeing that `GetIter<int>` doesn't have a `type` member. Since that isn't in the immediate context, this isn't a deduction failure - it's a hard error.

Note: even if this were a deduction failure, it would still only work for `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>`, not any vector.

**How to make it work**

Actually, you don't need SFINAE at all here. Just have one overload for `vector` and another overload for everything:

```
template <class T, class A>
auto f(std::vector<T,A>& t) {
    return t.begin();
}

template <class T>
T f(T& t) {
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Like I said this is a gross reduction of a real problem using boost::range_iterator. Your suggestions are correct for the code shown but in reality I'm distinguishing between types with sub-type 'iterator' and everything else so the shown level of complication is needed. You first answer seems like it's going to work and this answer has the explanation why. I'm thoroughly impressed that people can understand this stuff and super thankful for your help.

Comment: In case you're curious I'm making algorithm versions that allow containers as args. I'm using SFINAE to distinguish containers from iterators for instance copy(in_cont, out_cont) vs copy(in_cont, out_iter). I don't know which answer to choose since they are both important.

Comment: @tukra If your question isn't accurately reflecting what you need, how do expect us to help? I can't guess. Not all containers have a `::iterator` either.

Comment: It's always a interesting choice whether to distill a problem down to its root cause or to present it in its full context. In this case the full problem involves a complicated bunch of stuff from boost so it seemed prudent to start with the distilled case and mention that the case is synthetic. I've amended the question above with the real situation I'd like to solve. I guess I was skeptical that anyone would examine my problem if it meant diagnosing the problem inside boost. I can't figure it out though even with the very helpful suggestions here.

Comment: adding  "typename ST = typename range_const_iterator<typename remove_const<typename remove_reference<C>::type>::type>::type" to the template list for boost::range_iterator seems to work. I had to remove another seemingly unused template argument "typename Enabler=void" to not get a "too many template arguments" error. Hopefully it is not important but I can't tell. It makes no sense to me what it would be for.

Answer (score -1):

I think the non-vector GetIter missed a type function.
    template 
    struct GetIter {
        typedef T type;
    };

Comment: That's intentional. GetIter is meant to only produce iterator types or missing type if there is no iterator so that SFINAE knows to bail.